# How to navigate to a component different than app.component.ts?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I am new to Angular 2+ so this may be an obvious question.

I want to navigate to a user settings page where the navigation is a sidebar instead of a menu in the header. To do this, I figure I somehow need to navigate to a different root component (not app.component). How is this best solved in Angular?

Below you see what I mean with having the `<app-header></app-header>` in the app.component.html, which renders a navigation bar at the top of the page rather than on the left hand side.

**app.component.html**

```
  <app-header></app-header>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

  <app-footer></app-footer>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '@core/services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  // encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(public authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `app.component` is gonna be linked always with your `app.module`, but doesn't need to be the one where u create the whole layout.

You might want to leave it kinda empty with just a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` piece on your HTML, and create then different shell/layouts depending on the route.

Think about that the `app.component` it is going to be needed by the `index.html` file to reference your root component, but doesn't strictly need to contain any kind of layout. Then u can leverage the layout to child components.

Comment: That was a good answer and it may be THE answer. The reason I haven't done it this way is that I figured that the header and footer are going to be present in 99% of the cases, so I wanted to minimize the amount of code. If I do as you say, I would have to put a footer and header on every page I have, import it into my modules etc. Apart from making the code a little more verbose, wouldn't this affect performance given that the header and footer would have to be initialized and rendered for each route navigation? Or does it not make a difference and if so, why?

Comment: You’re missing some info. You can see this as a tree, app.component has a single router outlet. In there you can route 2 toplevel components (a and b) - each of which also contain a router outlet, one with header and footer, the other one without. You define ‘inner’ views as children of a or b and you’re done. Does that make sense?

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you @MikeOne.